# Reading IMAP emails with PHP, and suggested classes?

Tags: php, email, class, imap

I want to add to my app a thin email client where you can read/delete your emails. The problem is certain emails have inline attachments and there is apple mail and all sorts of attachment types etc. Is there a good class that does all the dirty work in regards to detecting the mail type and separating media etc from the email.

Comment: You can use a client mail directly, have look at this: http://www.noupe.com/ajax/10-ajax-webmail-clients.html

Comment: Ya, I've played with squirrelmail but I want something even liter. For example http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap but with very flexibly in handling attachments.

Comment: This site http://www.phpclasses.org have many classes for different categories, you can search for what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2351-PHP-Access-IMAP-mailboxes-without-PHP-IMAP-extension.html) to retrieve mails, but I personally recommend you to use [IMAP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php) instead. There're lots of examples in php.net to follow. To send emails I used [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).